# PHP with DOM can not get the description correctly

Tags: php, dom

I am using the following code to get the *first*  of a page. However I can not get it. What am I missing here ?

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadhtmlfile("");
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$descr = $xpath->query('//div[@class="description"]');
    print_r($descr);
```

Answer (score 1):

`query()` returns a DOMNodeList, to get the `<div>` DOMNode, you need to get it from the list:

```
$descr = $xpath->query('//div[@class="description"]')->item(0);
```

Now, `$descr` contains a DOMNode of the first `<div>` with class `description`.

Comment: I just tried your answer but I still don't get any content of the description.

Comment: Because it's a DOMNode. Do `var_dump( $descr->textContent);` and you'll see the text content.

Comment: Ok great. How do I include the `<p>` that are inside the `.description`?